# How to pack third party softwares along with my software package?

Tags: c#, .net, software-distribution

I've my software completely functional. Now I need to make an installer(pack) for it.

My software uses MySQL Server, .NET MySQL connector.

So, along with my assemblies I want to pack these MySQL softwares also so that my client can install everything at one go.

How do I do that? This is the first time I'm making an installer, I've no clue about how to do  it. So, please mention what all classes / documentation do I need to go through for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) to package your assemblies and pre-requisites, or you can use something like [InstallShield](http://www.installshield.com/) or [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) to do the job. Take note that you have to pay for both, though.

I am using Advanced Installer, and it is working very well for me.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what [Ngu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892697/how-to-pack-third-party-softwares-along-with-my-software-package/1892709#1892709) said, this question in SO [Using MySql From .Net - Licensing Concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280135/using-mysql-from-net-licensing-concerns) should be of some help.

Comment: +1 - this could be VERY important if your software uses a closed-source license.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the nullsoft installer http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page , which is free.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use InstallShield to create your installer.Generally, there are redistributable packages available. You can set these as pre-requisites in your installer using InstallShield. So, the installer first searches for these prerequisites on the target machine and makes sure that these components are installed before your product is installed.

You can also use InstallShield to make your installer compatible with different OS (versions of Windows, 32 and 64bit OS etc). But remember, you sure have to pay for InstallShield.

You might find this useful - 
[Adding the MySQL Connector ODBC Setup Prerequisite to a Project](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/robo/projects/installshield11-5helplib/MySQLODBCDriverSetupPrerequisite.htm)